# Include a full stack trace when logging errors with Monolog in Silex

Tags: php, silex, monolog

I have an application with debug enabled, errors converted to exceptions and a Monolog logger service:

```
ErrorHandler::register();
ExceptionHandler::register();

$app = new Silex\Application();

$logfile = dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/log/application.log';
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
    'monolog.logfile' => $logfile,
    'monolog.level' => Logger::DEBUG,    
));
```

I want to log errors to a file as detailed as on browser.

Example: I access a non existent URL and I get the next two errors on the browser:

```
2/2
Not NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 159:
No route found for "GET /xxx"

1. in RouterListener.php line 159
2. at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))
3. at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher)) in EventDispatcher.php line 164
...

1/2
ResourceNotFoundException in UrlMatcher.php line 102:
No routes found for "/xxx".

1. in UrlMatcher.php line 102
2. at UrlMatcher->match('/xxx') in RedirectableUrlMatcher.php line 30
3. at RedirectableUrlMatcher->match('/xxx') in LazyUrlMatcher.php line 51
...
```

But the only text that is logged is:

```
[2016-03-30 21:32:10] myapp.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /xxx" (uncaught exception) at ...route.../vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 159 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /xxx\" at ...route.../vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:159, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/xxx\". at ...route.../vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:102)"} []
[2016-03-30 21:32:10] myapp.INFO: < 404 [] []
```

Is there any way to log all errors thrown, and including a full stack trace?

Comment: Isn't the full stack trace included in the log? There is a trace right?

Answer (score 1):

You can write log formatter that will format error

Configure monolog:

```
$logfile = dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/log/application.log';
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
    'monolog.logfile' => $logfile,
    'monolog.level' => Logger::DEBUG,    
));

$app->extend('monolog', function($monolog, $app) {
    static $initialized = false;
    if ($initialized) return $monolog;
    $initialized = true;

    foreach ($monolog->getHandlers() as $handler)
        if ($handler->getFormatter() instanceof \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter)
            $handler->setFormatter(new \My\Formatter());

    return $monolog;
});
```

Formatter:

```
class \My\Formatter extends \Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter
{
    public function format(array $record)
    {
        $output = ...;
        return $output
    }

    public function formatBatch(array $records)
    {
        $output = ...;
        return $output
    }
}
```